# Quand ou comment utiliser l'infinitif ou l'impératif ?

Tags: conjugaison, mode-grammatical, infinitif, impératif

Je me pose souvent la question lors de la rédaction de mes rapports et des procédures techniques.
Comment faut-il faire l'accord d'un verbe dans son contexte de type exécution d'une action ?
Par exemple : *cliquez* ou *cliquer* sur « suivant » pour continuer l'installation ?
Un autre : *sélectionnez* ou *sélectionner*… xxx options ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quand il s'agit de donner des consignes impératif ou infinitif sont tous les deux possibles, le choix dépend du rapport que l'on veut établir avec le lecteur.

L'infinitif exprime un ordre général et impersonnel. L'impératif exprime un ordre plus personnel et plus proche du lecteur, de ce fait il est plus prescriptif et crée un lien d'obligation entre l'énonciateur et l’exécutant potentiel.

S'il s'agit par exemple de consignes qui doivent impérativement être exécutées dans le déroulement d'un processus interne à une unité de production j'emploierais l'impératif. S'il s'agit de consignes générales adressées à un public non ciblé j'emploierais l'infinitif.

Answer (score 4):

S'il s'agit de donner des consignes pour une procédure à exécuter immédiatement, l'impératif est le mode le plus naturel.

S'il s'agit d'un texte qui apparait sur un bouton et qui décrit l'action de ce bouton, il n'y a pas d'autre choix que l'infinitif. Pour décrire un effet on utilise toujours l'infinitif.

Pour énoncer des interdictions ou des règles, l'infinitif peut aussi être utilisé, c'est alors en quelque sorte une façon abrégée de citer des règles ou des instructions. Mais ces actions sont généralement introduites pas un titre comme « Attention » ou « De préférence », « Ne pas oublier de ». De tels textes se veulent généralement une source d'information plus qu'une invitation personnelle à suivre ou exécuter les actions.

Answer (score 1):

À mon avis, la réponse dépend du contexte. Par exemple : Si on donne des instructions décrivant pas à pas ce qu'il faut faire, c'est vraisemblablement l'impératif. Si il y a une série de choix introduites par « Maintenant vous pouvez », il faut l'infinitif.

Pour un locuteur natif, utiliser un verbe qui n'a pas des formes homophones (*faire* par exemple) est un moyen simple de savoir celle qu'il faut utiliser.

Answer (score 1):

If you are giving instructions to the user, use the imperative (or a softer formulation, but doing so may be too verbose depending on the context).  If you are putting labels on buttons, menu entries, and so on, use the infinitive to describe the action which will be done when activating that item.