# Comment faire une liste de tâches ?

Tags: verbes, temps-grammatical

Quand je fais une telle liste en anglais, j'écris des actions à l'impératif et des objects, comme ça :

> 1. Take out trash
> 2. Clean room
> 3. Laundry

Mais quand je le fais en français, mes verbes sont à l'infinitif parce que ça sonne le plus naturel à mes oreilles anglaises :

> 1. Sortir la poubelle
> 2. Nettoyer ma chambre
> 3. Linge

Y a-t-il un style typique ou une « règle » pour une liste française ? Comment les français font-ils une telle liste ?

Comment: I haven't seen the format enough times to justify giving a full answer, but to my ears, you've got it exactly right. The imperative would sound a little odd (like ordering oneself: "Sors la poubelle !"). And as English speakers would casually omit a verb for "laundry", French speakers can too. Although certain motivational authors might say you need an "action" tied to every to-do item. ;) However, "buanderie" is a laundry room or laundromat; if you mean "aller à la buanderie", okay, but simply doing the laundry would be summarized by the word "linge" instead.

Comment: Related: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/quand-ou-comment-utiliser-linfinitif-ou-limp%c3%a9ratif

Comment: buanderie is a laundry room so unless one has a château, aller there sounds a bit over the top. That said: la laverie is really a laundromat.

Comment: I would add that the list should be uniform, as a soft requirement: if you start the first 2 items with verbs, continue on with verbs: _laver le linge_.

Comment: @Frank I agree in any type of formal writing that parallelism is important; for a quick 'n' dirty "todo list," I use whatever clues me in to the task itself. In particular, I was trying to exemplify multiple different types of list items, in case the rules are different

Comment: For a quick 'n' dirty "todo list", there aren't really any rules of the French language :-)

Comment: @Lambie Oh, I see when I consult the dictionary that "buanderie" as laundromat is Canadian only. My mistake. All the more reason not to have it alone as a list item, though. :)

Comment: @Luke Sawczak There should be a button or something, where one could signal the type of French. :)

Comment: @Lambie En effet !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no such official rule in French. Your english ears are pretty right though: the most natural and logic way to list actions is to use the **infinitive form** (because that's what you **need** to do !).

> Aujourd'hui, *j'ai besoin de* :
>
> 1. Sortir la poubelle
> 2. Nettoyer ma chambre
> 3. Laver mon linge (sale)

But if this list is supposed to be read by you only, you can basically put any keyword you want (*chambre, linge, poubelle*), as long as you understand what you meant... ;)

---

Some additional tips for you, if this list was more than just an example for the question. As a French speaker, I would have said :

> 1. Sortir **les*** poubelles
> 2. Nettoyer ma chambre
> 3. **Faire une machine****

- * : Even though it might seem odd, it sounds *slightly* more natural to use *les poubelles* even if you have only one trash bag. *La poubelle* often refers to the trashcan itself, not the bag you put in !
- ** : If you are building something that looks like a to-do-list, perhaps you'd prefer using the informal (but super-cool, and widely used idiom !) *faire une machine*, that litterally means *doing the laundry* !

Comment: Merci de votre aide, surtout pour les trucs !

Answer (score 1):

Je vais parier que la règle est: utiliser la conjugaison qu'on utiliserait suivi de "Je dois".

"Je dois sortir la poubelle" -> "Sortir la poubelle"

"Je dois nettoyer ma chambre" -> "Nettoyer ma chambre"

"I have to take out the trash" -> "Take out the trash".

"I have to clean my room" -> "Clean my room".

En éliminant la partie invariable on tombe naturellement sur une liste de tâches.