# "Tutoyer" in software or conjugated words

Tags: informatique, vouvoiement, tutoiement

To me, it feels better if the following were conjugated *impératif* rather than *infinitif*:

- Sauvegarder
- Cliquer ici
- Enregistrer
- Organiser

I would prefer that the user be instructed to perform the actions shown on buttons or in links.  Like in English:

- Save
- Click Here
- Record
- Organize

What is the proper method of communication with a user?  *Tutoyer*? *Vouvoyer*?
Since in English, we frequently use the imperative and it can be translated to the second person singular form, to me, it feels like it is more personal.

I have users all over the world. Will choosing one seem too informal over the other?

Comment: I see infinitive and vous most of the time. But I don't use enough programs in French to say anything definite...

Comment: @LukeSawczak, you mention most of the time.  Have you seen something other than infinitive or vous?

Comment: Hmm, I was more just hedging my bets. I'd say that I haven't seen anything but those two, but my memory isn't detailed enough for me to confidently say "all of the time" :p

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/quand-ou-comment-utiliser-linfinitif-ou-limp%c3%a9ratif

Comment: Interesting. In my language (German), like in French, the infinitive is used on menu items and buttons. However, I never perceived the English texts as anything other than infinitive forms (with the *to* being dropped). I *might* interpret them as imperative directed at the computer/the application. Having instructions *for the user* on menu items or buttons does not seem to make any sense to me.

Comment: @ORM: For a confirmation it would be interesting to know what was done in old English em… not necessarily on computers :-) But you are certainly right.

Comment: **Maybe** it could help you (a little) to overcome the feeling of detachment from your users (which you mentioned in a comment, below) if you compromise and use the "vous form," but view/justify it in your own mind as you using it in the plural form to communicate with all your users simultaneously rather than in the formal one addressed to each individual user (along the lines of "Cliquez ici ="Click here, y'all/youse guysl"

Comment: I like what you said. @PapaPoule does the "vous" form, in the mind of a French speaker seem to communicate y'all more than a formal you?  I am probably just over thinking this, though when I develop my software, I feel deeply involved in it and I want users to have a connection, albeit vicariously, with me. I see my development as a kin to writing a book. Maybe this is way too deep here.  What I really want to know is if I tutoie will I offend any of several generations of people?  If yes then I will revert to the old archaic "standard" method of addressing users as suggested by most everyone.

Comment: In a perfect world the audience who would be offended/shocked by the "tu" form would/could interpret your "vous" form as formal and those who don't care would/could continue not caring and/or possibly see it as the plural, but I can't say for sure (not being a native speaker).  I would avoid the "tu" form, however, because that would remove any doubt in the minds of those who would be offended and/or find it strange.

Comment: @PapaPoule I spoke with a teacher yesterday, and I think you are correct.  She is a native speaker and she said you would never put the informal "tu" form.  Using the Imperative and infinitive is what is expected, though I wonder what Millennials think about the formal form.

Comment: 1 of 2…Imo, the best argument **against** using the “tu” form is that I can’t imagine that **anyone** (not even pesky Millennials, of which I’m the proud father of two) would be hurt/put off/offended/etc by you **NOT** using it. Furthermore, in addition to running the risk of “offending” old fogies visiting your site (granted, their visits/reactions don’t seem to be your greatest concern), using “tu” could actually backfire even with Millennials, who might see it not as your attempt to “connect” with them, but rather as you talking down to them. (to be continued)

Comment: 2 of 2...As a compromise, you could consider using the plural/formal imperative AT LEAST for “Cliquez ici” & if space permits you could even consider prefacing all your commands with “Cliquez ici pour+[whatever action in the infinitive],” like [here](http://www.prof2000.pt/users/anaroda/pfrances/index.htm). Just a thought, but would it be possible w/out too much effort to offer your users (w/the click of a button) the option early-on to be addressed from then on either formally or informally? Granted, that's obviously taking your "over thinking" to the next level, but it would be so cool, imo!

Comment: @PapaPoule I appreciate all of the comments and discussion.  It has been really fun and interesting to pursue this train of thought.  I will not use the "tu" form and work to find other ways to connect with my users.  I like the idea of "Cliquez ici pour faire une mesure".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by Luke Sawczak in the comments, most of software in French use the infinitive form for these verbs.

If you're using these verbs in the context of a tutorial or a guide on how to use this software, you could use the "vous" form. If you want to convey a sense of proximity, then use the "tu" form.

Comment: Not just most software: this is how instructions are written in French. It applies to cooking recipes, to instructions on how to build furniture, ...

Comment: Aren't we supposed to progress though.  I feel so detached from my users if I have to use the infinitive form or vovoyer.  It seems so retro, like 1970.   I don't have a mobile phone from France, do they use the infinitive?  What about modern websites? Eh ben, j'ai visité quelques sites et j'ai trouvé qu'il utilisent infinitif et vovoient sur la même page.

Comment: I can well imagine English programs that would be unusually familiar, such as Tumblr. For example, one of their 404 messages ends: "Unless you were looking for this error page, in which case: Congrats! You totally found it." A French program taking such a tone *tutoierait-il*, I wonder?

Comment: Just switched my Tumblr to French. « Ou peut-être vouliez-vous visiter cette page d'erreur ? Auquel cas : bravo ! Vous avez réussi ! » So a no-go on that one. (Also, this is admittedly outside of the scope of instructions anyway.)

Comment: Blizzard's [404](http://us.blizzard.com/en-us/404notfound): "Grats. You broke it." En [français](http://eu.blizzard.com/fr-fr/404notfound): "Ah, ben bravo. Vous avez tout cassé." I'm not holding out much hope now.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your audience.

If you have a software for any user, we normally use "*vous*", since we don't know the user and that your software may be for professionnals (where we mostly use "*vous*").

If your software is for children (i.e. Adibou), you can use "*tu*" 
(e.g. "Clique sur le carré", "Aide-le à retrouver son chien").